# What is this file icon with blocks which is found in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

Can someone help me identify what this Solution Explorer icon is. I have reviewed the Images and Icons article from Visual Studio but I don't see a icon similar to this icon.
here is the link to the article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2015

The Icon:[image]

Answer (score 1):

These designate *building block* type files which may actually span multiple files more than just that one file.

For example one may have a service that has a designer file underneath. Another example is a project installer file (cs) which has the cs file, a designer.cs file and a resx file.

By opening up the file you will see other **grouped**
 files underneath.

The files do share the [components interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icomponent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) which allows sharing between apps and serves as the basis for all other components in the CLR.

---

[image]